# Projecting $\mathbb{H}YP_\mathfrak{M}$ over $\mathfrak{M}$: an intuitive explanation?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

In the work of Barwise on Admissible sets and structures, theorems II.5.14, V.5.3, and VI.4.11/12 show how to project the smallest admissible set over a structure $\mathfrak{M} = (M, R_1, …, R_n)$, $\mathbb{H}YP_\mathfrak{M}$, into the domain of $\mathfrak{M}$, $M$. I was wondering if anyone had an intuitive explanation of how to do it, or at least an easy example of how to do it (e.g.  using as base structure the structure $\mathbb{N}$).
The basic idea seems to be: we can code $\mathbb{H}YP_\mathfrak{M}$ in the set of hereditarily finite sets $\mathbb{H}F_\mathfrak{M}$ over the universe of sets on $M$ (V.5.3), which in turn can be coded in $M$ (VI.4.11), and this makes it possible to have a notation system for $\mathbb{H}YP_\mathfrak{M}$ in $M$. Can you provide a concrete example of how to do this with $\mathbb{H}YP_\mathbb{N}$ (which contains the hyperarithmetic sets) in $\omega$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that there is a $\Sigma_1$-over-$L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ injection of $\omega_1^{CK}$ (and so $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ as well) into $\omega$? Barwise's result is a generalization of this fact, so I'd start with it first.

Comment: Dear Noah, thank you for the reply! Can you please give me a reference?

Comment: This is covered in Sacks' book [*Higher recursion theory*](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Higher-Recursion-Theory/toc/pl/1235422631) (using the phrase "the $\Sigma_1$-projectum of $\omega_1^{CK}$ is $\omega$" or similar). Basically, the idea is that given an ordinal $\alpha$ we search through $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ for a pair $(n, f)$ where $n$ is an ordinal notation (a la Kleene) and $f$ is a function witnessing that $n$ is a notation for $\alpha$, and map $\alpha$ to the $n$ of the first such pair found. This is appropriately $\Sigma_1$ over $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$.

Comment: Dear @NoahSchweber

Sorry if I get back to this after ages. Your comment was actually really useful! I had another question, if you don't mind. Let π be a $ℍ_$-recursive projection of $ℍ_$ into . The domain of , $_π$, cannot be hyperelementary over : if it were, then by Σ-replacement, $ℍ_$ ∈ $ℍ_$. My question is, is $\omega^{ck}_2$ the ordinal of $\mathbb{H}YP_{(,_π)}$? Intuitively, $ℍ_$ ∈ $ℍ_{(,_π)}$, since $\forall x \in D_{\pi}\,.\,\exists y\,.\,\pi(y) = x$. Thanks again for your help!